# Is it possible to pass an extra parameter to a mongoose update callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoose update call and would like to pass an extra parameter...like so:

Trying to pass **isLoopOver**

```
UserInfo.update({_id: userInfo._id}, {'value': someval}, function(err, numAffected, isLoopOver ) {
    console.log('IsLoopOver ' + JSON.stringify(isLoopOver) );
    if (isLoopOver){
        doSomething(isLoopOver);
    }
});
```

Tried the above but I get an object (inside the callback) as below:

```
{"updatedExisting":true,"n":1,"connectionId":117,"err":null,"ok":1}
```

No idea why it is showing the status from mongo.

Question: How can I pass an extra parameter thru the callback?

Comment: Can you tack it onto your userInfo object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The common way is:

```
var isLoopOver = false;
UserInfo.update({_id: userInfo._id}, {'value': someval}, function(err, numAffected) {
    console.log('IsLoopOver ' + JSON.stringify(isLoopOver) );
    if (isLoopOver){
        doSomething(isLoopOver);
    }
});
```

If you are worried about some code will change the value of `isLoopOver` before the `update`'s callback function being called, using the following code:

```
(function (isLoopOver) {
  UserInfo.update({_id: userInfo._id}, {'value': someval}, function(err, numAffected) {
      console.log('IsLoopOver ' + JSON.stringify(isLoopOver) );
      if (isLoopOver){
          doSomething(isLoopOver);
      }
  });
}(isLoopOver));
```

The reason why your `isLoopOver` variable is showing the status from mongo is that in the callback function, the `isLoopOver` is a formal parameter instead of a actual parameter.

Comment: What about if i do 
`function a(paramw) {
var isLoopOver = paramw;
UserInfo.update({_id: userInfo._id}, {'value': someval}, function(err, numAffected) {
    console.log('IsLoopOver ' + JSON.stringify(isLoopOver) );
    if (isLoopOver){
        doSomething(isLoopOver);
    }
});
}

a(false);`
Will i have to worry that callback will use the new value of the given parameter if i call the function again before the first' time call's callback is solved? 

a(false); will the callback invoked from this take false also is a(true) is called before the callback is invoked? @RamIyer

Comment: @Morrisda No, you won't have to worry about it. The value of `params` won't change inside the function.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Underscore's [partial function](http://underscorejs.org/#partial):

```
UserInfo.update(..., _.partial(function( isLoopOver, err, numAffected ) {
}, isLoopOver ))
```

Comment: Or [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partial_Functions).