# For Loop inside node request, not executing as expected

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am new to node and I am struggling with whats happening here:

```
app.get('/set_users/', function(req, res){
    var users = [
        {
            email: "tom@gmail.com",
        },
        {
            email: "jon@gmail.com",
        }
    ];


    for(i=0; i<users.length; i++){

        console.log("Logging index");
        console.log(i);

        User.findOne({email: users[i].email}, function(err, user){

            console.log("Printing index");
            console.log(i);

            if (err){
                //Do something with error;
            }

            if (user) {
                //User already exists - do something
            }
            else{
                //Add new user
            }
    }
});
```

I would expect the output from the console.log statements to be:

```
logging index
0
logging index
1
Printing index
0
Printing index
1
```

However instead I am getting:

```
logging index
0
logging index
1
Printing index
2
Printing index
2
```

Anybody any ideas what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using help from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16879859/1493564

The answer I came up with was this:

```
app.get('/set_users/', function(req, res){
    var users = [
        {
            email: "tom@gmail.com",
         },
         {
             email: "jon@gmail.com",
         }
     ];


    for(i=0; i<users.length; i++){

        console.log("Logging index");
        console.log(i);
        (function(i){
             User.findOne({email: users[i].email}, function(err, user){

                console.log("Printing index");
                console.log(i);

                if (err){
                    //Do something with error;
                }

                if (user) {
                    //User already exists - do something
                }
                else{
                    //Add new user
                }
         })(i)
    }
});
```

Not sure if anyone knows of a better solution?

Comment: Thats one of the possible solutions. You're using a function closure to keep the parameter in that particular scope. I would improve upon your example by creating a function ("getUserByEmail" or similar), as then you can reuse it if it might be useful somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the variable used in the callback is not changed by the other iterations:

```
for(i=0; i<users.length; i++){

    var currentUserIndex = i;

    User.findOne({email: users[i].email}, function(err, user){

        console.log("Printing index");
        console.log(currentUserIndex);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a callback function to User.findOne which is being fired after your for loop completes (with value of 2). User.findOne is an asynchronous function so it it will fire the callback when its done.

Comment: How would I avoid this happening then? somehow passing in the value  of i to the callback?